# ¿Es posible realizar un SELECT en SQL server que me arroje solo los nuevos registros desde la última consulta realizada?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla a la cual se le están ingresando registros constantemente y necesito crear un SP que cada que lo ejecute muestre los nuevos registros ingresados, es decir, sin mostrar los que ya me mostró en la consulta anterior.
Ejemplo: si desde la última consulta han ingresado 5 nuevos registros, que cuando corra de nuevo el SP me muestre solo esos 5 registros nuevos.

Muchas gracias!

El código que tengo es:

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INSTRUCCIONES_GIRO @ultimo_registro INT
AS
SELECT

```
        [monto],
        referencia = CASE WHEN [referencias] IS NULL OR [referencias] = '' THEN '#' ELSE [referencias] END,
        [el_beneficiario_es],
        [numero_cuenta_del_beneficiario],
        [nombre_del_beneficiario],
        direccion_del_beneficiario = CASE WHEN [direccion_del_beneficiario] IS NULL OR [direccion_del_beneficiario] = '' THEN '#' ELSE [direccion_del_beneficiario] END,
        numero_de_la_cuenta_banco_beneficiario = CASE WHEN [numero_de_la_cuenta_banco_beneficiario] IS NULL OR [numero_de_la_cuenta_banco_beneficiario] = '' THEN '#' ELSE [numero_de_la_cuenta_banco_beneficiario] END,
        [nombre_del_banco_beneficiario],
        nombre_banco_intermediario = CASE WHEN [nombre_banco_intermediario] IS NULL OR [nombre_banco_intermediario] = '' THEN '#' ELSE [nombre_banco_intermediario] END

    FROM REMITENTES
    WHERE ID > @ultimo_registro;
```

GO

Comment: Bienvenido Jonatan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Respuesta rápida No, al menos no es funcionalidad que te dé el Motor. Lo que preguntas se puede programar, necesitas llevar un registro de que filas se consultaron, seguramente por usuario, para no volver a recuperarlas en la siguiente consulta.

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede!!! que intentaste?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es un SP.. por supuesto que se puede, haciendo todo lo que decis.. entonces la respuesta rapida es se puede... ahora el como.. es otro tema...

Comment: @gbianchi, si claro.. el tema es que por el título "SELECT en SQL server que me arroje solo los nuevos registros", me parecía mejor un "No, pero..." que un "Si" tajante.  Ciertamente si Jonatan puede ampliar un poco más su pregunta, agregando un ejemplo, lo que hubiera investigado o intentado, tal vez se podría desarrollar una respuesta concreta para ayudarlo más allá de los comentarios que le podamos dejar.

Comment: Yo intenté filtrarlo con un WHERE y el ID que va aumentando de 1 en 1 cada que ingresa un nuevo registro, dejé el código que tengo en la descripción de la pregunta, pero no sé cómo guardar en esa variable el valor de la última consulta para que me filtre bien el where

Comment: Lo tenes que guardar en una tabla, y tomarlo cada vez que entras...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.